# How to handle embedded properties using <f:field> tag on GSP in grails 3.3.11?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-plugin, gsp, grails-domain-class

I have to assign values to the embedded properties of domain class.

```
class Person{
String name
Address address
static embedded=['address']
}

class Address{
String country
}
```

I am able to add name using the following tag

```
        <f:field bean="person" property="name">
            <g:textField name="${property}" value="${value}"/>
        </f:field>
```

How do i assign value to embedded property "country" of Address class?

Answer (score 0):

> How do i assign value to embedded property "country" of Address class?

The `static embedded=['address']` aspect of this doesn't really have any impact. That affects the persistence model.

If you have a form field named `address.country` and use that to bind to a `Person` instance, that will get to the `country` property in the `Address` object that is contained in the `Person` instance.

Comment: How do i customize UI for the embedded property of Address?

Comment: "How do i customize UI for the embedded property of Address?" - What do you want to show up in the UI?

Comment: Syntax for single address object and list of address objects